# Creating new rails action doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, action

i have a controller "Apps". It consists of one action "index". Now I want to add a new action called "buy":

```
def buy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

i added a buy.html.erb to the views, but when browsing to /apps/buy, i get following message:

```
Unknown action - The action 'show' could not be found for AppsController
```

in the routes I added this:

```
  match '/apps/buy', :controller => 'apps', :action => 'buy'
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The url is being caught by the standard `/apps/:id` route, I assume you also have `resources :apps` in your routes?

Simply place the buy route first:

```
match '/apps/buy', :controller => 'apps', :action => 'buy'
resources :apps
```

Bear in mind that routes are executed in the order they are defined, so the specific ones need to precede the general.

A simpler approach as @Ryan suggests is adding a collection route to the resource:

```
resources :apps, :collection => { :buy => :get }
```

Comment: Alternatively add the `buy` action as a collection route to your `resources :apps`.

Comment: I think this is outdated for Rails 3. Instead you need to do something more like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: @JasonAxelson no it's not outdated, just a different syntax for the same thing.