# Simple Rails routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am having another ruby nuby moment and can't seem to wrap my head around this simple problem.

I have this as a route:

```
resources :pages
```

I have this in my pages controller:

```
def testy

end
```

and I have this in app/views/pages/testy.html.erb

```
<h1>Testy</h1>
```

I am trying to access the page like so: http://localhost:3000/pages/testy

And I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Page with ID=testy
```

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/pages/testy" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 09 14:24:51 -0600 2010
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"testy"}
[1m[35mPage Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE ("pages"."id" = 0) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 12ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Page with ID=testy):
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

It's obvious by the log that it's trying to access #show, but why? I think it's a problem with my route. Can someone give me a quick pointer?

I was following the [Rails Guides here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and I think this is what is throwing me off "... the rule is that if you do not explicitly render something by the end of the controller action, rails will look for the action_name.html.erb template in the controllers view path and then render that, ..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating new rails action doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312477/creating-new-rails-action-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set up a RESTful route like `resources :pages`, by default anything after `pages/` in the URL is put into the params hash as an ID so `pages/1` would give you a params hash that includes `{:id => '1'}` (among other things like `:controller`, `:action`, etc.).

There is an exception for certain actions like `pages/new` or `pages/edit` . Rails is smart enough to know that 'new' and 'edit' are not IDs. You just need to tell rails that 'testy' is not an ID either.

You can define custom actions using `member` or `collection` inside a block attached to `resources` like this:

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get :testy  # will match pages/testy
    get :foo
    post :bar
  end

  member do
    get :baz # will match pages/1/baz
  end
end
```

Now rails will know that `pages/testy` is a custom route and will not interpret 'testy' as an ID. Make sure your route names are never the same as your ID. In other words, if you had a `Page` that had an id of `testy` for some reason, you'd never be able to reach it given the above routes!

For deeper knowledge, I highly recommend the official rails guide on routes:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Kind of long, but definitely worth the time to read.

Comment: @jyoseph Glad that helped. I updated the answer to use `collection`.

Comment: I'm okay nesting multiple collections in there right? I did and it seems to be okay. so `collection do get:testy end collection do get :cal end`

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to repeat `collection`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Option 1*

```
  resources :pages do
    collection do
      get :testy
    end
  end
```

results in:

```
testy_pages GET /pages/testy(.:format) {:action=>"testy", :controller=>"pages"}
```

*Option 2*

```
  resources :pages do
    member do
      get :testy
    end
  end
```

results in:

```
testy_page GET /pages/:id/testy(.:format) {:action=>"testy", :controller=>"pages"}
```

*Option 3*

```
  resources :pages do
    get :testy
  end
```

results in:

```
page_testy GET /pages/:page_id/testy(.:format) {:action=>"testy", :controller=>"pages"}
```

Any of these might be useful, though I think Option 1 is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

in your routes file

```
resources :pages do
  get 'test'
end
```

that will work. replace with post if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to run `rake routes` or write routing tests/specs

Answer (score 0):

Since pages is a resource anything after it in the url will be an `id` with the stock options.

If you want to have a definition with 'testy' as the name you need to add a `named routed` to your `routes.rb` such as:

```
map.test 'testy', :controller => "pages", :action => "test"
```

Then to link to this you will need to call `<%= link_to "testy", testy_path %>`